# How to trigger change on file input in ember integration test?

Tags: unit-testing, ember.js, mocking

I'm trying to write an integration test for a file upload component but aren't able to trigger a change event on input type file. While jQuery listener is triggered, embers change event is not fired.

I'm mocking an event with a simple object and passing this one to jQuery `trigger` method. It's working fine if I don't set `target` property of mocked event. In these case jQuery event handler and ember event are fired.

I'm mocking files with [Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) objects and using that ones as `target` property of my mocked event. If I'm passing this one to trigger jQuery event handler is still fired but ember event is not.

This is how it looks in code.

```
// mock a file
let file = new Blob(['content'], { type: 'image/jpeg' });
// mock an event
let event = { type: 'change' };
// set events target
event.target = { files: [file] };
this.$('input').trigger(event);
```

I've created a Ember Twiddle demonstrating that `this.$('input').trigger({  type: 'change' })` triggers ember change event but `this.$('input').trigger({ target: { files: [file] }, type: 'change' })` does not while both is working for jQuery event handler: https://ember-twiddle.com/5189be1875c147e96d31dea41668b006?openFiles=tests.integration.components.file-input-test.js%2C

It was working in early ember versions but didn't used for a longer time so I'm not quite sure when it was broken.

Using `jQuery.Event('change')` instead of a plain object shows same results. So this is also not working:

```
jQuery.Event('change');
event.target = { files: [file] };
this.$('input').trigger(event);
```

Please note hat `document.createEvent()` or `new Event()` can't be used since `target` property of [Event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/Event) object is readonly.

I'm especially confused that `this.$('input').on('change', () => { })` is triggered while change event of ember is not.

Update: I'm not quite sure if it's ever worked in ember. I noticed that the example I had in mind ([ember-cli-file-pickers uploadFileHelper](https://github.com/funkensturm/ember-cli-file-picker/blob/master/test-support/helpers/ember-cli-file-picker.js#L18-L27)) may only work since it's not using embers change event but [registers a jQuery event handler](https://github.com/funkensturm/ember-cli-file-picker/blob/master/addon/components/file-picker.js#L51-L53) in didInsertElement hook.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Ember test helper `triggerEvent`.

I look like this

```
import { triggerEvent } from '@ember/test-helpers'
...
triggerEvent(selector, eventName, options)
```

I've implemented a file upload event like this
`triggerEvent(selector, 'change', files)`

Here is the doc: https://github.com/emberjs/ember-test-helpers/blob/master/API.md#triggerevent